# Spivak's Calculus, chapter 5 question 42 without being "completely fallacious"

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

[image: Last Question of Ch.5]

I'm wondering is this proof will fix the issue of being "completely fallacious" - or is it still circular?

-

Consider the function $f(x)=x^2.$ The aim is to prove its continuity using interval notation. Let $a\in \mathbb{R}.$ We need to check that given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ satisfying $a-\delta<x<a+\delta$ one has $a^2-\epsilon<x^2<a^2+\epsilon.$  To understand what must be the value of $\delta,$ we observe that 
$$
x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a).
$$
If we know that $|x-a|<\delta,$ then $|x|<\delta+|a|$ and
$$
|x^2-a^2|=|x-a||x+a|<\delta(|x|+|a|)<\delta(2|a|+\delta).
$$
Take $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2a+1})$ and let $a-\delta<x<a+\delta.$ Then 
$$
x^2=a^2+x^2-a^2<a^2+\delta(2|a|+\delta)\leq a^2+\delta(2|a|+1)\leq a^2+\epsilon
$$
and 
$$
x^2=a^2+x^2-a^2>a^2-\delta(2|a|+\delta)\geq a^2-\delta(2|a|+1)\geq a^2-\epsilon
$$
Finally, if $a-\delta<x<a+\delta,$ then $a^2-\epsilon<x^2<a^2+\epsilon.$

Comment: I think that this is exactly the proof with the factoring "trick" that he wanted to circumvent with the "fallacius" argument. Even to just prove that the integer powers are monotonously increasing you use the binomial factoring formula for the power differences.

Comment: I think it would be pedagogically better to first teach a general result that if $F=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $G=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ then $FG=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x),$ which is easily shown without using roots, nor factoring tricks, nor  any mention or assumptions about continuity. Then, for example, let $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Concerning te "fallacy" see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/195726 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof that you wrote down, completely correctly, is the standard one, and it uses the "factoring" mentioned in the cited text that the "fallacious argument" was thought to avoid. The "factoring" is exactly the use of the binomial formula
$$
x^2-a^2=(x-a)(x+a)\\
x^3-a^3=(x-a)(x^2+xa+a^2)
$$
that stands at the start of your proof.

Just any property of the square root function $\sqrt{x}=\sup\{r\in\Bbb R_+:r^2\le x\}$, that it is well-defined, monotonous, continuous, makes use of the same properties of the square function which are proven starting from this factorization.