# Where is the fallacy in this "proof" of $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$?

Tags: calculus, limits, fake-proofs

I just started reading Michael Spivak's *Calculus* and I am at Chapter 5 - *Limits* now. I tried doing the problems, and at the very end is an interesting and hard problem (problem 41) which I really can't see the solution:

(This problem is in Spivak's personal view.)

> **41.** After sending the manuscript for the first edition of this book off to the printer, I thought of a much simpler way to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$ and $\lim_{x \to a} x^3 = a^3$ without going through all the factoring tricks on page 95. Suppose, for example, that we want to prove that $\lim_{x \to a} x^2 = a^2$, where $a > 0.$ Given $\epsilon > 0$, we simply let $\delta$ be the minimum of $\sqrt{a^2 + \epsilon}  -a$ and $a - \sqrt{a^2 - \epsilon}$ (see Figure 19); then $|x - a| < \delta$ implies that $\sqrt{a^2 - \epsilon} < x < \sqrt{a^2 + \epsilon}$, so $a^2 - \epsilon < x^2 < a^2 + \epsilon$, or $|x^2 - a^2| < \epsilon$. It is fortunate these pages had already been set, so I couldn't make these changes, because this "proof" is completely fallacious. Wherein lies the fallacy?

I don't know where the fallacy is, but either way, the "proof" that he gave was very promising and for me, it's hard to find the error.

> So what *is* the fallacy in Spivak's "proof"?

Comment: Do you mean to write $\epsilon > 0 $ ?

Comment: Oops, yeah. Sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: Had a feeling that was too easy to be the mistake lol

Comment: Somewhat *off-topic*: a way around this mess is the theorem in Real Analysis that the product of the limits is the limit of the product.  That is, prove that $$\text{if} ~~ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L ~~\text{and}~~ \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = M ~~\text{then}~~ \lim_{x\to a}\left[f(x) \times g(x)\right] = (L \times M).$$

Comment: @user2661923: +1 for your comment. If one understands the proof of limit laws, then any typical $\epsilon, \delta $ exercise can be managed by just adapting the proof of limit laws to that specific example. Hence the emphasis should be on understanding why and how these limit laws work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having taught out of that book something like 15 times, let me give the answer. We do not yet know — rigorously — that $\sqrt x$ exists. That will be proved as a consequence of the Three Hard Theorems, several chapters later.

Comment: Interesting. This means that one cannot answer the question without knowing the structure of Spivak's book.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to prove that every positive number has a square root without appealing to the continuity of the function $x\mapsto x^2$? I know that this is the approach that Spivak takes, but I'm wondering if there are other approaches.

Comment: @PaulFrost Not so different from many questions on this site for which we need to know what’s in the OP’s toolkit in order to respond meaningfully.

Comment: Usually, imho, the answer to such a question should be seen in the quoted text itself. How can we know what else may not be determined if we have not studied the entire book in detail?

Comment: @Joe: I am confident that you will need the least upper bound property of $\Bbb R$. That indeed comes later in the text. Note that it fails for $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I had a look into Spivak's book and found that he very frequently uses square roots **before** he proves their existence on p. 122.  Thus the fallacy in Spivak's "simpler solution" of Problem 41 is a fallacy in all parts of his book coming before Chapter 8 "Least Upper Bounds" where he introduces axiom (P13) on p.133. He seems to be aware of that problem; on p.127 he writes *Now that we have discovered this fallacy, it is almost obvious what additional properties of the real numbers we need. All we must do is say it properly and use it. That is the business of the next chapter.*

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, this means that without knowing the structure of the book, we cannot answer this question. Suppose that we have this in Terrence Tao's Analysis, where real exponentiation (and therefore the square root) is defined BEFORE limits of functions. Then Spivak's "proof" WOULD BE COMPLETELY LEGIT.

Comment: @Paul Frost You are right: Spivak invokes $\sqrt{2}$ well before its existence is proven. Similarly, several problems involve results from geometry, or make use of the trigonometric functions before those have been formally defined.

This sort of "cheating" is restricted to isolated problems;  $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sin{x}$ don't appear in any important early *proofs*. 

However, this distinction can be confusing to the reader, especially since certain other problems **do** contain important results that are used in later arguments.

Comment: @Paul Frost (cont) The "cheating" does allow more interesting problems, but it might have been better if it was acknowledged more explicitly.

Comment: @Ben I absolutely agree and do not think it is a big problem to refer to "commonly known" expressions like $\sqrt x$ or $\sin x$ before they have been introduced in a formal and precise way later in the book. Perhaps Spivak distinguishes between "formal use" in theorems (or proofs) and "informal / naive use" in exercises. The first occurrence is on p.12 where he says "Here, and throughout the book, $\sqrt x$ denotes the *positive* square root of $x$; this symbol is only defined when $x \ge 0$." It would have been nice if he had remarked that the **existence** of $\sqrt x$ will be proved later.

Comment: But as I said  - not an important point of criticism. Anyway, it may be confusing for newbies to find Exercise 41 just after Exercise 39.

Comment: @TedShifrin, when you taught from it, what was the course, single variable calculus? For freshman?

Comment: (Honors)Calculus with Theory, @Joe. Yes, freshmen, and the occasional math education grad student.

Answer (score 1):

What is $\sqrt{x}$? Typically one defines it by appealing to the intermediate value theorem, which requires continuity of $x\mapsto x^2.$

Comment: How does Spivak construct the reals? If you use Dedekind cuts, isn't $\sqrt{x}$ just the cut of all rationals whose square is less than / greater than or equal to $x$ (for $x>0$)?